# Brightway2 : import simapro file but error with biosphere file

Tags: python, brightway

I have a problem with an import from SimaPro : I have imported one .csv file, everything works well. I can modifiy my database and visualize it on Activity-Browser but when I tried to calculate, a biosphere file seems to miss:

```
sp=bi.SimaProCSVImporter(r"C:/Users/TD264999/Documents/BDD_export/Outil_TrE/eol.csv","BDD_eol")
sp.statistics()
sp.apply_strategies()
sp.migrate("simapro-ecoinvent-3.3")
sp.match_database("ei33", ignore_categories=True)
sp.statistics()
sp.apply_strategies()
```

```
143 datasets
1527 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: update_ecoinvent_locations
Applying strategy: assign_only_product_as_production
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: sp_allocate_products
Applying strategy: fix_zero_allocation_products
Applying strategy: split_simapro_name_geo
Applying strategy: strip_biosphere_exc_locations
Applying strategy: migrate_datasets
Applying strategy: migrate_exchanges
Applying strategy: set_code_by_activity_hash
Applying strategy: link_technosphere_based_on_name_unit_location
Applying strategy: change_electricity_unit_mj_to_kwh
Applying strategy: set_lognormal_loc_value_uncertainty_safe
Applying strategy: normalize_biosphere_categories
Applying strategy: normalize_simapro_biosphere_categories
Applying strategy: normalize_biosphere_names
Applying strategy: normalize_simapro_biosphere_names
Applying strategy: migrate_exchanges
Applying strategy: fix_localized_water_flows
Applying strategy: link_iterable_by_fields
Applying strategy: convert_activity_parameters_to_list
Applied 22 strategies in 0.51 seconds
```

```
sp.write_database()
```

```
act = bd.Database("BDD_eol").random()
ipcc = ('IPCC 2013', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a')
lca = bc.LCA({act: 1}, method=ipcc)
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
print(lca.score)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [244], in <module>
      1 lca = bc.LCA({act: 1}, method=ipcc)
----> 2 lca.lci()
      3 lca.lcia()
      4 print(lca.score)

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\lca_algebraic\lib\site-packages\bw2calc\lca.py:338, in LCA.lci(self, factorize, builder)
    320     def lci(self, factorize=False,
    321             builder=TBMBuilder):
    322         """
    323 Calculate a life cycle inventory.
    324 
   (...)
    336 
    337         """
--> 338         self.load_lci_data(builder=builder)
    339         self.build_demand_array()
    340         if factorize:

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\lca_algebraic\lib\site-packages\bw2calc\lca.py:217, in LCA.load_lci_data(self, fix_dictionaries, builder)
    211 """Load data and create technosphere and biosphere matrices."""
    212 self._fixed = False
    213 self.bio_params, self.tech_params, \
    214     self.biosphere_dict, self.activity_dict, \
    215     self.product_dict, self.biosphere_matrix, \
    216     self.technosphere_matrix = \
--> 217     builder.build(self.database_filepath)
    218 if len(self.activity_dict) != len(self.product_dict):
    219     raise NonsquareTechnosphere((
    220         "Technosphere matrix is not square: {} activities (columns) and {} products (rows). "
    221         "Use LeastSquaresLCA to solve this system, or fix the input "
    222         "data").format(len(self.activity_dict), len(self.product_dict))
    223     )

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\lca_algebraic\lib\site-packages\bw2calc\matrices.py:143, in TechnosphereBiosphereMatrixBuilder.build(cls, paths)
    141 """Build the technosphere and biosphere sparse matrices."""
    142 assert isinstance(paths, (tuple, list, set)), "paths must be a list"
--> 143 array = load_arrays(paths)
    144 # take ~10 times faster than fancy indexing
    145 # http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=215
    146 tech_array = cls.select_technosphere_array(array)

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\lca_algebraic\lib\site-packages\bw2calc\utils.py:35, in load_arrays(objs)
     32     arrays.append(obj.copy())
     34 for obj in sorted([o for o in objs if is_filepath(o)]):
---> 35     arrays.append(np.load(obj, allow_pickle=True))
     37 for obj in sorted([o for o in objs if is_other(o)]):
     38     arrays.append(np.load(obj, allow_pickle=True))

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\lca_algebraic\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py:407, in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    405     own_fid = False
    406 else:
--> 407     fid = stack.enter_context(open(os_fspath(file), "rb"))
    408     own_fid = True
    410 # Code to distinguish from NumPy binary files and pickles.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\TD264999\\AppData\\Local\\pylca\\Brightway3\\import_BDD_ecoinvent.b8499629751d715829a9e9cc3bdb3ffe\\processed\\biosphere3.5d405d71.zip'
```

And in fact there is no .zip file with this name but some .npy files named : biosphere3.5d405d7124beac53e64a4cd0f9e012f4.geomapping.npy and biosphere3.5d405d7124beac53e64a4cd0f9e012f4.npy.

Does someone know how to deal with this issue please?

Best regards,
Tristan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple versions of Brightway installed, and their processed array formats are not compatible. You should only use each project with either Brightway 2 or 2.5.

`biosphere3.5d405d71.zip` is in the 2.5 format (from [bw_processing](https://github.com/brightway-lca/bw_processing)).

`biosphere3.5d405d7124beac53e64a4cd0f9e012f4.npy` is the Brightway 2 format.

You can fix this by reprocessing the array, i.e.

```py
from bw2data import Database
Database('biosphere3').process()
```

You can also reprocess everything and reinstall the default LCIA methods and data migrations:

```py
from bw2data import Updates
from bw2io import create_default_biosphere3, create_default_lcia_methods
Updates._reprocess_all()
create_default_biosphere3(overwrite=True)
create_default_lcia_methods(overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Hello Chris,
Thanks for the answer. In fact, I had a problem because I exported a project from a computer with a version 2.5 and I imported it on a computer with a previous version. 
Thanks again ! 
Tristan

Comment: I still have 1 issue with versions. It did not worked when I did Database('biosphere3').process() . The problem is that I have some files with the format "biosphere-2-3-categories.c4c23e4d.json" in Brightway3/project/migrations and "biosphere-2-3-categories.c4c23e4d830d2b633703f1a65f9cdd0f.json" in my default project. 
I do not how to fix it... I tried to reimport a project which have the same version but now in Brightway3/project/processed, type files are not npy but for exemple impact-2002-endpoint-obsoleteet.c610aacf848866d6 is .c610aacf848866d6 and the same for my DB. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Edited answer to reprocess more things.

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks for the edited answer. The problem persists, the migration files between the default project and my project are still different. I also tried to do it manually but I still cannot make calculations. I also tried to delete and create the default project again but without success.

Comment: There are a number of ways to solve this, but by far the simplest would be to create a new conda or virtual environment, install only `brightway2` (and the AB if you want), and start a new project.